# Get Updated Row Count in Transaction Scope

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

I am doing some insertion operation in SQL server within TransactionScope.

Here is my code

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    Int32 existingDBRowCount = GetTableRowCount(currentTableName);
    //... Code to Insert Data into Table
     Int32 newDBRowCount = GetTableRowCount(currentTableName);

    // New Row Count should be equal to Existing DB Row Count + Rows to be inserted
     if (newDBRowCount != (existingDBRowCount + toBeInsertedRowCount))
          Transaction.Current.Rollback();
     else 
       scope.Complete();  // Commit the Transaction
}


public Int32 GetTableRowCount(string tableName)
{
  using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = GetSQLConnection())
  {
     if (sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        sqlConnection.Open();

      string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [" + tableName + "]";
      using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
      {
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = queryString;

        var rowCount = (int) sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        return rowCount;
       }
    }
 }
```

Basically What i am doing is I keep a track of count of Rows in the table and then after Inserting new data, I check if new row count = exisiting Rows + Count of Rows to be Inserted

If Both matches, I commit the transaction, otherwise rollback

I have two questions:

1) Is this apprach correct ?

2) In some cases new DB Row Counts is coming as same as existing rows, I assumed that it is because my transaction hasn't been committed till that point, but it is very random, mostly it returns correct number of rows. I cant figure out whats going wrong

Comment: No that approach isn't correct. Everything depends on your logic which is executed inside transaction. But you should be able to achieve any synchronization level you need using Transaction Isolation Levels. They may prevent other transactions from inserting rows in a range which is locked by your transaction. Read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms173763.aspx. But don't be too restrictive - that will decrease performance. Select the minimumn level that will ensure consistency of your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want correct number of rows even without Commiting Data, You need to set IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted while reading Table Row Count

```
SqlTransaction transaction = SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

and then assign this transaction to your SQL Command

See this Link [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)